# Change Chunk Size On Existing Software raid 0 Array

Tags: mdadm

Is it possible to change the chunk size on an existing software raid 0 array?

Operating system: Ubuntu 10.04 64bit

Mdadm Version: Version : 2.6.7.1

Kernel:2.6.32-33

Comment: What is the purpose of your RAID0 - why do you want to change the chunk-size and how many physical disks are involved or available?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on kernel version and `mdadm` version. The fastest way to check is to search `mdadm` manual for `chunk-size`. mdadm manual from Fedora 15 has a `CHUNK-SIZE AND LAYOUT CHANGES` section.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a raid 10 with a new raid0 that has your wantet chunk-size.
After that you can degrade to raid0 again.